# Magento 1 - Is this if-else-condition possible in layout XML?

Tags: layout, magento-1, ifconfig

I want to display two different CSS

```
<action method="addItem" ifconfig="module/general/enable">
    <type>js_css</type>
    <name>module/app.css</name>
</action>
```

In XML we use `ifconfig` but I want to add two different CSS files like this

```
if (marketplace/general/enable == 1) {
     css-1
 } else {
     css-2 
 }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no "inverse directive" to `ifconfig`. You can still have the *name* parameter calculated by a helper method like this:

XML:

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>js_css</type>
    <name helper="helpername/helpermethod"/>
</action>
```

`helpername` is the identifier that you usually pass to `Mage::helper($name)` and `helpermethod` the method you want to call.

In your module's helper class (pseudo code):

```
public function helpermethod()
{
    if ($enabled) {
        return 'module/app1.css';
    } else {
        return 'module/app2.css';
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it work in magento 2?

Answer (score 5):

use this [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extended-ifconfig.html) for extended config option

you can use `condition` tag for tag

```
<action method="addItem" ifconfig="module/general/enable" condition="1">
    <type>js_css</type>
    <name>module/app.css</name>
</action>
<action method="addItem" ifconfig="module/general/enable" condition="0">
    <type>js_css</type>
    <name>module/app1.css</name>
</action>
```